# Python3 Filtering through a Nested list using a user input or return all cases given a special character

Tags: search, python-3.x, lambda, nested-lists

I'm trying to figure out how to filter a nested list by a given user input or return all cases if the user types in "*"

For example: for a nested list like this:

`st_list = [["11","adge",22,"email"], ["0","adge",21,3.44,"email"], ["2","adge",33,3.43,"email"], ["1","ared",43,3.55, "email"]]`

I'm trying to filter the nested list by each sublist's index, so that for st_list[1][i] where the element at [i] equals the user input, those items will be returned.

I have no issue when using a specific input (srch_name in this case).  I've been using:

`new_list = list(filter(lambda n:n[1]==srch_name, st_list))`

However, I'm not really sure how to return any case when the user enters the "*".  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what exactly you want, and I can't think of a beautiful one-liner to do what I _think_ you want, but why can't you just do a simple `if` statement? `if input() == "*": return st_list`.

Comment: In retrospect, I didn't make things clear.  What I was trying to do was return every sublist if "*" was given or only return "adge" if the user typed "adge".  I figured out a solution though.  In my lambda, have n[1]==srch_name or srch_name =="*".  This way it evaluates True for either case and will return my lists.

Comment: Glad you could suss it out :) I suggest you write out your solution as an answer and accept it so future readers can also benefit.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer from my question.  So for the user input, srch_name, my lambda function will return True if the user input equals n[1].  In my st_list, those would evaluate for "adge", "adge", "adge", and "ared".  So if a user input was "adge", only those lists with adge would be returned.  If I wanted it to return for all cases given a specific input, say "*", then setting srch_name = to "*" would evaluate true regardless.  Thus,:

```
new_list = list(filter(lambda n:n[1]==srch_name or srch_name == "*", st_list))
```

would return everything.